# Laravel Cart not picking up food price

Tags: laravel

Am building an ordering system for restaurants
When one clicks order here it takes the user to the cart page>this  is the link that takes the user to the cart page

```
<p class="btn-holder"><a href="{{ route('restaurants.cart',$restaurant->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center" role="button" > Order this</a> </p>
```

but my cart page isn't displaying the food price.It displays it as 0 yet the price exists.

```
    <table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:50%">Product</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Price</th>
            <th style="width:8%">Quantity</th>
            <th style="width:22%" class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
            <th style="width:10%"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php $total = 0 ?>

        @if(session('cart'))
            @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)

                <?php $total += (int)$details['price'] *(int)$details['quantity'] ?>

                <tr>
                    <td data-th="Product">
                        <div class="row">
                            {{-- <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs"><img src="{{ $details['photo'] }}" width="100" height="100" class="img-responsive"/></div> --}}
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <h4 class="nomargin">{{ $details['name'] }}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="Price">{{(int) $details['price'] }}</td>
                    <td data-th="Quantity">
                        <input type="number" value="{{ $details['quantity'] }}" class="form-control quantity" />
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">{{(int) $details['price'] *(int) $details['quantity'] }}</td>
                    <td class="actions" data-th="">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm update-cart" data-id="{{ $id }}"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-from-cart" data-id="{{ $id }}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif

        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr class="visible-xs">
            <td class="text-center"><strong>Total {{ $total }}</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Continue Shopping</a></td>
            <td colspan="2" class="hidden-xs"></td>
            <td class="hidden-xs text-center"><strong>Total ${{ $total }}</strong></td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

@endsection
```

This is the Foods controller and  function addToCart which adds items to cart

```
public function addToCart($id){
        $food = Food::find($id);


        if(!$food) {

            abort(404);

        }

        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        // if cart is empty then this the first product
        if(!$cart) {

            $cart = [
                    $id => [
                        "name" => $food->food_item,
                        "quantity" => 1,
                        "price" => $food->price,

                    ]
            ];

            session()->put('cart', $cart);

            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
        }

        // if cart not empty then check if this product exist then increment quantity
        if(isset($cart[$id])) {

            $cart[$id]['quantity']++;

            session()->put('cart', $cart);

            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');

        }

        // if item not exist in cart then add to cart with quantity = 1
        $cart[$id] = [
            "name" => $food->food_item,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "price" => $food->price,

        ];

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    }




}
```

Comment: ```<td data-th="Price">{{ $details['price'] }}</td>``` Try removing the entire conversion casting and see what it returns to you?

Comment: it displays the food name instead of price

Comment: Could you please show the method of your controller and your affected model to see what is happening in more detail? Thank you.

Comment: @NewWorldNeverland already updated my code with the controller

Comment: Please ```dd($food)``` after checking that it is not empty and show the result. Thank you. It is very strange, if the price gives 0 it is because it is not an integer value, since as he said when removing the casting he got the name of the food. Then let's see what the debug of $ food throws and we can see what is happening there.

Comment: I tested the above code and the prices are displayed correctly. Incrementing the quantity also works fine.